How to recursively join subsets into a list in python?
I have a list of sets:
my_set = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 5], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8]]

I want to join all subsets that have elements in common (at least with one subset) in this list, into a single subset:
my_final_set = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 8]]

In this case, the the elements 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 must be grouped in a single final subset, as the image shows. How can I do it in Python?

I think I should do some recursive approach, but I couldn't think of a way to do it.

You have a list of lists, not a list of sets.

Can there be further levels of nesting? If not, I don't think you need recursion.

Loop through the elements of the list. Check if it has any overlap with any of the elements of the result list. If it does, combine it with that element. Otherwise, append it to the result list.

If you need something more efficient, you can make a dictionary whose keys are the inner list elements, and values are the element of the result list containing that number. Then to tell if there's an overlap you can just test whether any of the inner list elements are already a key.

Please show what you tried. I can give you design hints, and help you fix your code, but we won't write it for you.

You can take two sets and reduce it:

def get_union(sets):
    def _rec(S, B):
        A = set(S)
        i = 0
        while i < len(B):
            if A.intersection(B[i]):
                A.update(B.pop(i))
                A, B = _rec(A, B)
            else:
                i += 1
        return A, B

    res = []
    while sets:
        C, sets = _rec(sets[0], sets[1:])
        res.append(list(C))
    return res


print(get_union([[1, 2, 3], [1, 5], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8]]))


Prints
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [8, 7]]

This seems a perfect candidate for a disjoint set data structure. Apply the union operation to link numbers that belong to the same set. Once that is done for all sets, produce the result by reading out the above data structure:
# Implementation of Union-Find (Disjoint Set)
class Node:
    def __init__(self):
        self.parent = self
        self.rank = 0

    def find(self):
        if self.parent.parent != self.parent:
            self.parent = self.parent.find()
        return self.parent

    def union(self, other):
        node = self.find()
        other = other.find()
        if node == other:
            return # was already in same set
        if node.rank > other.rank:
            node, other = other, node
        node.parent = other
        other.rank = max(other.rank, node.rank + 1)

from collections import defaultdict

def merge(sets):
    nodes = defaultdict(Node)
    for first, *rest in sets:
        for item in rest:
            nodes[item].union(nodes[first])
    merged = defaultdict(list)
    for item, node in nodes.items():
        merged[node.find()].append(item)
    return list(merged.values())

print(merge([[1, 2, 3], [1, 5], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8]]))


I'd suggest using a single collections.Counter to track the elements that appear in more than one set, and then use that to sort the sets into overlapping vs non-overlapping.  Here's a quick demo:
from collections import Counter

my_sets = [{1, 2, 3}, {1, 5}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8}]

counts = Counter(i for s in my_sets for i in s)
merged_set = set()
remainder = []
for s in my_sets:
    if any(counts[i] > 1 for i in s):
        merged_set |= s
    else:
        remainder.append(s)

gives us:
>>> [merged_set] + remainder
[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, {8, 7}]

Note that this depends on my_sets being a collection of sets, not lists as in your original question.  If it's a collection of arbitrary lists, modify the Counter so that it only counts one item per sublist by turning it into a set before it's counted:
counts = Counter(i for s in my_sets for i in set(s))

